# When using 3 text boxes for date form

Tags: asp.net, textbox, controls

I have have date form on my web page and it is just 3 text boxes, 1 for day 2nd for month and 3rd for year as dd/mm/yyyy. What I wana do is when some one enters two digits for the day the cursor should automatically jumps to the month text box , and then to the year text box i.e instead of clicking or hitting tab button......I was messed up with it this after noon and can't finish it. lol. Any help!

Comment: PLease don't do that.  It's really annoying.  Most users will press tab out of habit, and then they'll be in the wrong field.  Even better, just use one text box.

Comment: I completely agree with @awm. I have cursed god knows how many devs for doing this all over the internet.

Comment: Using one field will also mean 1/3 less validation for you to write.

Answer (score 0):

Try this little bit of JS:

```
function moveToNext(field,nextFieldID){
  if(field.value.length >= field.maxLength){
    document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
  }
}
```

and then add this to your fields:

```
<input type="text" id="dd" maxlength=2 onkeyup="moveToNext(this,'mm')"/>
<input type="text" id="mm" maxlength=2 onkeyup="moveToNext(this,'yyyy')"/>
<input type="text" id="yyyy" maxlength=4 />
```

Comment: @user646508, @awm, @dawson, @Soumya92 - thanks all. I learnt from the @user646508 code, I also accept @awm advise.

Comment: @Tim Stone , @user646508, How can I do the same using <asp:textbox> as there is no onkeyup event in textbox.